# Why doesn't my tic tac toe in C detect a winner properly?

Tags: c, tic-tac-toe

I have a simple Tic Tac Toe program that should work but doesn't. I have only made one win condition and it doesn't seem to be met even if I manually set all of the spaces to x. I've tried debugging it in Visual Studio Code but it doesn't always work and can be annoying it seems like it isn't calling to the function and I'm unsure of why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//        l       l
//    0   l   1   l   2
//        l       l
// ***********************
//        l       l
//    3   l   4   l   5
//        l       l
// ***********************
//        l       l
//    6   l   7   l   8
//        l       l


char space[9] = {'p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p'};//p is just a placement value
unsigned int currentPlayer = 1;
bool winner = false;
int p1;
int p2;

int win();

int win(){
    if(space[0] == 'x' && space[1] == 'x' && space[2] == 'x'){
        printf("Player 1 wins");
        winner = true;
    }
}


int main(){
    while(winner == false){//winenr becomes true when someone wins

        
        //The Board//
        printf("       l       l       \n   %c   l   %c   l   %c   \n       l       l       \n***********************\n       l       l       \n   %c   l   %c   l   %c   \n       l       l       \n***********************\n       l       l       \n   %c   l   %c   l   %c   \n       l       l       \n\n",space[0], space[1], space[2], space[3], space[4], space[5], space[6], space[7], space[8]);
        
        if(winner == false){
        //Player 1's turn//     
            while(currentPlayer == 1 && winner == false){//to keep the loop going if they make a wrong move

                win();//to refer back to the win function to see if win conditions are met

                printf("Player 1:");
                scanf("%d", &p1);
                printf("\n\n\n\n");
            

                if(space[p1] == 'x' || space[p1] == 'o'){//if the space is equal to either letter that means they need to input a new move
                
                    printf("That space is currently taken pick another space\n\n");
                }
                if(space[p1] != 'x' && space[p1] != 'o'){//if neither space is equal to a letter then you can put your move there
                    space[p1] = 'x';
                    currentPlayer = 2;
                    break;
                
                }
                else{ 
                    printf("invalid input\n\n");
                }
            

            } 


            while(currentPlayer == 2 && winner == false){//player 2's turn

                printf("Player 2:");
                scanf("%d", &p2);
                printf("\n\n\n\n");

                if(space[p2] == 'x' || space[p2] == 'o'){
                
                    printf("That space is currently taken pick another space\n\n");
                }
                if(space[p2] != 'x' || space[p2] != 'o'){
                    space[p2] = 'o';
                    currentPlayer = 1;
                    break; //changing the player
                }
                else{ 
                    printf("invalid input\n\n");
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for some rease #include <stdio.h> was not included in my post but it is there

Comment: Also i apologize if I've done something wrong in submitting this im new to the site any help or advice would be appreciated

Comment: The line with triple backticks should contain only the language name (or `none`).  It must be separate from the actual code.

Comment: Your function `win()` is defined to return an integer, but it doesn't actually return anything. That should be causing compiler warnings unless you're adhering to the original C90 standard which is over 30 years old and has been obsolete for over 20 years. You should make the function return a value — probably `winner` — and you should check the return value when you call the function. If there's a winner, you should break the loop. It seems to me you should check for a winner after each player plays. (I don't think using `exit()` in the `win()` function is a good solution, for all it works.)

Comment: Also, since this is C and not C++, the declaration `int win();` does not declare a prototype for the function, so you can call the function with arbitrary arguments and the compiler can't complain.  You should use `int win(void);` in the declaration, and the function definition (symmetry, consistency, reliability).

Comment: `(space[p2] != 'x' || space[p2] != 'o')` will always be true.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help its caused me to not just learn more about the code, but also help with my little project!

Answer (score 0):

When your "win" condition is satisfied it *is* printing the message - but then you don't terminate the program. It just continues. Replace `winner = true;` with `exit(0)` in `win()`. You also need to call `win()` *after* a piece is added to the board, not before. And do that for both player 1 and player 2.

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems like I was just unaware i had to do that. Thank you so so much.

Comment: Yes, you can do that.  No, I don't think it is a good way around the problem.  All else apart, it prevents the option of "Play Again?".

Comment: And you can certainly make things more complex - `setjmp/longjmp` anyone? :-) - but here we have a newbie programmer asking for some advice, so I'm not going to make it complicated - just enough to get OP back on track and thinking for him/herself.